# Spivak Sine confusion (possible error)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

quote from Spivak:

"Let us consider the function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$." The goal is to show it is false that as $x \to 0$ that $f(x)\to 0$

He says we have to show "we simple have to find one $a > 0$ for, which the condition $f(x) < a$ cannot be guaranteed, no matter how small we require $|x|$ to be. In fact $a = 1/2$ will do. **It is impossible to ensure that $|f(x)| < 1/2$ no matter how small we require $x$ to be.**" (Spivak 93).

Okay, major issue here.

$\sin(1/x) < 1/2$
$ \implies 1/x < \arcsin(1/2)$
$ \implies 1/x < \pi/6$
$ \implies 6/\pi < x$

I just proved $\sin(1/x)$ can be less than 1/2. what is Spivak talking about?!?

Comment: Apart from the reasoning itself, your implications pointing the wrong (=useless) direction. You are looking for a condition that will imply $\sin(1/x)<1/2$, not for one that is implied by it. Also your final condition is requiring $x$ to be large, not small (in absolute value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be less than $\frac12$. But what Spivak is saying is that you can't make it *always* be less than $\frac12$ just by keeping $x$ close to zero. It will oscillate up and down, up and down, up and down, no matter how close to zero $x$ gets. You can't escape the oscillatory behavior, even if you keep $x$ inside $(-0.0000001,+0.0000001)$.

The reason is that the reciprocal $\frac1x$, which is what you end up taking the sine of, after all, grows without bound the close $x$ gets to zero.

Comment: he says you cant ensure it. Does he mean you cant **always** ensure it, or you cant ensure it **at all**, which i disproved.

Comment: He means always. Condition A ensures condition B if A implies B; B is sure (meaning with 100% certainty, or always) to be true provided that A is true. Spivak is saying this is NOT the case. "A" is "take $x$ very close to zero, and "B" is "$|\sin\frac1x|<\frac12$". He is saying A does not ensure B. You have shown that the function *can* be less than $\frac12$, he wants that the function *must* be less than $\frac12$, and is saying you can't guarantee it.

Answer (score 2):

He is saying that there are *arbitrarily* small values of $x$ such that the $|f(x)<1/2|$ is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Your first step is not correct: arcsin just gives you one possible argument, not the only one.

Example: you can have $sin(x)<0$ but not $x<arcsin(0)=0$, just take $x=3\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

put the sequences $x_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$ or $x_n=\frac{1}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})\frac{\pi}{2}}$ in your function and show that a limit doesn't exist